# Low FPS and high memory usage with background image

Tags: background, processing

I have a scene with orbiting 'planets', some orbiting others and all orbiting a sun in the centre.

When I run the code with the following it runs well.

```java
void draw() {
background(0);
```

If I run this second example, there is a low frame rate and nearly 1Gb of memory is used.

```java
void draw() {

  PImage img;
  img = loadImage("stars.jpg");
  background(img);
```

Is this because of poor code and if so, what aspect should be changed?

I need the background re-drawn every frame as otherwise, the moving objects, 'draw' their path as they move.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't call the `loadImage()` function from the `draw()` function.

You're reading the file 60 times per second, when you only really need to read it **once**. Declare images at the sketch level, load them from `setup()`, and draw them from `draw()`. Like this:

```
PImage img;

void setup(){
   img = loadImage("stars.jpg");
}
void draw() {
  background(img);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So, it wasn't the drawing that was causing problems, it was disk access speeds 60x /s.